# problems deploying project in Worklight 5.0.6

Tags: tomcat, openjpa, ibm-mobilefirst

Running Worklight 5.0.6 on Tomcat 7 with MySQL 5.6

I dropped all the previous databases and let the Install Manager recreate them. The console runs fine and I am able to upload the wlapp and adapetrs. However, after deploying myproject.war I get the following error every 5 seconds:

```
SEVERE: Persistency data access problem
com.worklight.core.exceptions.PersistentDataAccessException:
Persistency data access problem at com.worklight.core.exceptions.DefaultExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultExceptionHandler.java:50) at com.worklight.core.tasks.TaskThread.run(TaskThread.java:100)
Caused by:
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Can only perform operation while a transaction is active.;
nested exception is <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error>
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Can only perform operation while a transaction is active.
```

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Databases: APPCNTR, WLREPORT, WRKLGHT

Content of the context.xml

```
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/WorklightDS"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  maxActive="100"
  maxIdle="30"
  maxWait="10000"
  username="worklight"
  password="***"
  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/WRKLGHT"/>
<Resource name="jdbc/WorklightReportsDS"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  maxActive="100"
  maxIdle="30"
  maxWait="10000"
  username="worklight"
  password="***"
  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/WLREPORT"/>
<Resource name="jdbc/AppCenterDS"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  maxActive="100"
  maxIdle="30"
  maxWait="10000"
  username="worklight"
  password="***"
  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/APPCNTR"/>
</Context>
```

Tomcat's web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/WorklightDS</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/WorklightReportsDS</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

worklight.properties

```
wl.db.jndi.name=java:comp/env/jdbc/WorklightDS
wl.db.type=MYSQL
```

Here are the steps in more details:
Yes, here the steps:

1. Use IM to install worklight 5.0.6.1 - this puts three webapps in my Tomcat folder: appcenterconsole.war, applicationcenter.war, and worklight.war
2. Run console (runs successfully): `http://hostname:8080/worklight/console`
3. Create a hybrid project in eclipse which this generates myprojectname.war file in the /bin folder
4. Update the publicWorkLightContext, publicWorkLightPort,  wl.db.type, wl.db.jndi.name variables found in the workllight.properties file in the server/conf folder of my project.
5. Rename the myproject.war to myappname.war to match the value of the publicWorkLightContext variable
6. Manually drop the myappname.war file under the webapps folder of  Tomcat (this is when the error starts appearing)
7. Additionaly upload the adapter and wlapp files through the worklight console. This step works fine and I can see the respective records created in the databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure there is only 1 Worklight .war file deployed.

Per the steps you've mentioned, it seems like you did not remove the current worklight .war file from Tomcat prior to dropping the new .war file. There can be only 1 Worklight .war file at a time.

1. Go to `http://yourhost:8080/manager` and make sure you disable and undeploy the current  Worklight .war file.
2. Using the Tomcat manager, deploy the new .war file
3. Go to `http://yourhost:8080/yourcontext/console` and deploy the apps from the related Worklight project

Comment: I used Installation Manager to upgrade from 5.03. I then dropped all the previous databases and manually recreated them. The war file is only one. The jee jar file is the latest as well. I pretty much went step by step through the manual install and config steps for tomcat/mysql.

Comment: I guess they only option is then to wipe out everything clean and do a complete new install

Comment: The IBM Installation Manager has an Uninstall option. Use this option first if you choose to go the re-installation path.

Comment: It could be that since you dropped and re-created the databases yourself, you may have given them the wrong name (they are case-sensitive, depending on your system and database software), or may have mis-configured the worklight.properties of your project, depending on your (new) setup.

Comment: Add that information to your question for review, perhaps it is salvageable... databases names (remember, case-sensitive), as well as contents of worklight.properties, your operating system, etc...

Comment: Complete re-install did not help either. See the updated question above. All databases been dropped and I let the InstallManager re-create them

Comment: My apologies. I thought that mentioning that the console runs fine and that I am able to deploy the adapter and the wlapp file would eliminate the database connectivity suspicion (I am able to see the records in the db tables)

Comment: My understanding is that everything works fine if you use the pre-deployed worklight.war (comes with the IM installation), but as soon as you deploy your own customized .war file (from your new Worklight project) (via the Tomcat manager), and then deploy apps from the same new project, it then fails. Can you describe your steps from after installing Worklight on Tomcat and then trying to deploy your .war file?

Comment: See my edited answer. It does look like you didn't remove the previous .war file (you did not mention this).

Comment: Idan, thanks for your persistence and patience. I totally misunderstood the relationship between the worklight.war and myproject.war and did not realize that the console is being deployed with the latter one as well. The 10_01 guide makes it clear that only one war can be deployed per app server.